# Access useParams hook from Navbar or static component in react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I get a Navbar at the top of every page to have access to `react-router` `useParams` hook?  With the below code `User` will have `userId` returned, but `Nav` gets an empty object.

It looks like a component (element) needs to be rendered inside a `Route` to use this hook but in v6 all routes are "exact" so I don't see a way for a static component to render on every path.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Nav /> // How does this component show on every page and get access to route params?
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/user/:userId' element={<User />} />
    <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `Nav` component to render with each page/route *and* able to access any route path params then you can create a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) that renders the `Nav` component and an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#outlet) component for the nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Nav />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/user/:userId' element={<User />} />
      <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```